# Who is that? Where does it all happen?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, steganography

[image: Thursday]
[image: Saturday]
[image: Bonus stuff]
[image: Monday]
[image: Long time after]
[image: Wednesday]
[image: Sunday]
[image: Friday]
[image: Tuesday]

Who is that? Where does it all happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's

> Harry Potter

And it all happens, of course,

> in Hogwarts!

Explanation:

> Every picture references the title of one of the HP books, or a character of the series. In order:
>  1: The **order** of the Phoenix
>  2: The **deathly** hallows
>  3: That's a griffon, referencing Buckbeak, the hippogriff from the 3rd book
>  4: The **chamber** of secrets
>  5: Not quite sure about this. A young "dark lord", such as the young version of Voldemort that appears in the 2nd book, perhaps? Or maybe, Kylo Ren being the leader of the First Order could be another reference to the **Order** of the Phoenix...
>  6: The **goblet** of fire
>  7: The philosoper's **stone**
>  8: The half-blood **prince**
>  9: The **prisoner** of Azkaban

Comment: You missed only 3 (by a bit) and 5 (by large). But your answer is correct nevertheless. Fix'em and I will accept your answer.

Comment: The griffon might be for Gryffindor

Comment: Ren/ Slay the Ren or something along those lines for Slytherin?

Comment: @as4s4hetic solved the missing references [in his answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60504/5044). Since now, the puzzle is completelly solved, I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Adding onto Teo's answer:

> The descriptions of all these pictures are the 7 days of the week as well as "Bonus stuff" and "Long time after". The 7 days correspond to the 7 books in order (Sunday = Philosopher's stone, Monday = Chamber of secrets etc.). This gives us a hint for what pictures 3 and 5 are.

Missing answers:

> 3. **Bonus Stuff**: This references [*Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them_(film))
>  5. **Long time after**: This is probably [*The Cursed Child*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Cursed_Child), written a long time after the original series and by a different author, much like the new Star Wars series.

Comment: Correct! Now it is completelly solved. I'll accept [Teo's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60480/5044), but your answer finished it. Consider this as an honorable mention!

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the additional books!