# Who is that? Where does it all happen? 2

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

1. **Who is that?**
2. **Where does it all happen?**
3. **What measures against COVID-19 are in practice?**

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Note: [similar older question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/60474/5044).

Comment: I want to upvote, but your reputation is 8888 ...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be

> several characters from Mortal Kombat, many of who wear masks.

They're probably in

> Outworld.

Specifically, we have:

> Sub-Zero

> Rain

> Scorpion

> Smoke

> Noob Saibot

> Kano

> Tremor

> Liu Kang

> Reptile

Comment: Rot13(Nyzbfg gurer. Xnab naq Yvh Xnat ner jebat.)

Comment: Is 8 perhaps rot13(Xvat Tbeonx)?

Comment: @Prim3numbah No.